# Ignore join if method argument is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method:

```
def self.sap_qualified(start_at, stop_at, zip)
    course_ids = Course.where('sap_qualifying IS true OR sap_renewing IS true').collect{|c| c.id}
    if course_ids.any?
      course_class_ids = CourseClass.where(course_id: course_ids).collect{|c| c.id}
      if course_class_ids.any?
        joins(:class_registrations).
        joins(:primary_billing).where("postal_code =?", zip).
        where(:class_registrations => {course_class_id: course_class_ids}).
        where('class_registrations.score ~ ? AND CAST(class_registrations.score as int) >= ? AND class_registrations.exam_completed_at >= ? AND class_registrations.exam_completed_at <= ?', '^[0-9]', 80, start_at.to_date.beginning_of_day, stop_at.to_date.beginning_of_day)
      else
...
```

...this works has expected if the user includes a zip code (third argument). However, if the user leaves the zip field blank I would like to run the query without the join statement for the zipcode.

I could do something like

```
if !zip.blank?
  one query...
else
  same query as above, but with the joins(:primary_billing).where("postal_code =?", zip)...
```

...but that feels janky and violates about  dozen DRY principals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ActiveRecord statement in your query returns a Relation, you can save it to intermediate variable:

```
  if course_class_ids.any?
    relation = joins(:class_registrations)

    if zip.present?        
      relation = relation.joins(:primary_billing).where("postal_code =?", zip)
    end

    relation = relation.where(:class_registrations => {course_class_id: course_class_ids}).
    where('class_registrations.score ~ ? AND CAST(class_registrations.score as int) >= ? AND class_registrations.exam_completed_at >= ? AND class_registrations.exam_completed_at <= ?', '^[0-9]', 80, start_at.to_date.beginning_of_day, stop_at.to_date.beginning_of_day)
  else
```